# Action Script expecting identifier before leftbrace

Tags: flash, actionscript, syntax, identifier

I've been doing alot of searches but everything I've found and tried has not solved my problem. I know very little about flash programming but I have this code I need to fix and I haven't the slightest idea what to do to stop getting this syntax error:

"£RROR: _d.as, Line 7: Syntax error: expecting identifier before leftbrace."
for the code:

```
package{
    import flash.display.*;

    dynamic public class _d extends MovieClip{

        public function _d()
        {
            return;
        }// end func

    }
}
```

I'm in a rush to fix this and have no ideas on how so any help would be appreciated. Also if anyone knows a better flash editior(freeware) than Sothink SWF Quicker, I'd be grateful for that assistance too.

P.S. Several files have this error, this file just had the simplest code to show

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles for me when I set it as the document class for an AS 3.0 project in Flash CS 5. I would suggest removing the `return` statement as constructors in ActionScript 3.0 should not return anything.

On the subject of naming your classes, the convention in ActionScript is to use CamelCase (see `MovieClip`, `TextField` etc.). A class named _d does not, I suspect, make for very readable code (but of course you may have your own reasons for naming your classes in this way).

[FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) is an excellent ActionScript 3.0 code editor, though it won't give you the timeline and graphic creation functions you get from Sothink or the Flash IDE itself.

Comment: But would removing the return statement cause any problems if the original code expected it to return the way it is shown above? As for the naming i'm aware of this, but it wasn't my idea to name it this way ;)  I'll see if FlashDevelop will work for me and if not i'll try removing the returns and see if that fixes the syntax error, thx a bunch~

Comment: Is the class in your question from a third-party library you're using?

Comment: uhh... I'm not sure exactly how flash works so.. i'm not sure. i just got a compiled SWF which SWF quicker turned into a bunch of *.AS files(some in the root directory, some in sub-directories). though to me it would seem as if that isn't a third-party lib.

Comment: Okay so you're trying to run some code you've decompiled. Why not stick what you have in a zip file and post the link here? I'll have a look and see if I can see what the problem is.